# SQL Server Restore Error: Directory lookup for the file "db.mdf" failed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When trying to restore a `dbname.bak` file (from a windows machine) for SQL Server on a linux machine using:

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname
FROM DISK = '/path/to/dbname.bak'
```

I got the following error:

> Error: Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\DATA\dbname.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>   SQLState:  S0001
>   ErrorCode: 5133

and also another error for the `dbname_log.ldf` file.

Why is SQL Server trying to reference windows files on a linux machine, I hear you ask?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Explanation**

MS SQL Server assumes by default that the file path(s) saved inside the `dbname.bak` is where the database should be restored to. If the file path(s) don't exist, you'll get an error like that.

**Solution**

Explicitly tell the DB to use a different file(s). But first you need to know how the file(s) is (are) referred to by executing the following T-SQL:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/path/to/dbname.bak'
```

which might give you something like this:

```
Dbname_Empty
Dbname_Empty_log
```

which you can then use to execute the following T-SQL:

```
RESTORE DATABASE dbname
FROM DISK = '/path/to/dbname.bak'
WITH MOVE 'Dbname_Empty' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/dbname.mdf',
MOVE 'Dbname_Empty_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/dbname.ldf'
```

hopefully without getting any errors.